# Multiple ng-class attributes on a directive

Tags: angularjs, directive, ng-class

[Relevant plnkr.](http://plnkr.co/edit/KKubPjxzD1mUSCrUi6Bv?p=preview)

In `script.js` I have a directive `super`. This directive has a template

```
template: '<div class="super" ng-class="{dirClass: foo}"></div>'
```

with an `ng-class` attribute.

Note that the directive also has `replace: true`.

The `<super>` element that calls this directive in `index.html` has an `ng-class` attribute as well. Apparently Angular doesn't like this.. It'll try to parse

```
[{viewClass: !bar} {dirClass: foo}]
```

which obviously fails. I expected it to be merged automagically.. nope.

I think that what I'm trying to achieve is kinda clear, but how would I go about doing it?

Comment: angular just concatenates attributes, it wont touch them

Comment: I saw the issue. You should open a ticket in the github. This should merge it.

Comment: I think there are already multiple issues related to this opened in the github. That is why they decided to deprecate the `replace:` flag, see: [eec6394a](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/eec6394a342fb92fba5270eee11c83f1d895e9fb) for a long discussion.

Comment: @runTarm Damn.. Seems like my half-year-old decision to stick with `replace: true` on my directives to avoid custom elements in the DOM was a mistake.. Well, hindsight is always 20/20.

@Fals [I created an issue and it got closed pretty quickly.](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/8491)

Comment: Yeah, I feel the same. I hope they would change their mind or provide any pratical alternative.

Answer (score 1):

you can do that in this way :http://plnkr.co/edit/xEc0pRHVbVLgR0NhWPEI?p=preview

js:

```
angular.module('app', [])
  .controller('myCtrl', function ($scope, $interval) {
    $scope.bar = false;

    $interval(function () {
      $scope.bar = !$scope.bar;
    }, 500);
  })

  .directive('super', function () {
    return {
      restrict: 'EA',
      template: '<div class="super" ng-class="{dirClass: foo , viewClass: !foo}" ></div>',
      scope: {
        foo: '='
      },
      replace: true
    };
  });
```

HTML:

```
 <super foo="bar"></super>
```

Comment: What I need is the ability to add another layer of `ng-class` to the directive in the view, which apparently isn't possible.. at all.

Comment: @WillB, that's right but you can pass demanded value to directive and set class inside directive

Comment: I'm not really following you.. what do you mean?

Comment: @WillB for what reason do you want add another layef of ng-class. Just pass values to directive and set css class inside directive